# Is there a way in Postgresql to query the entire JSONB record in a column?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgresql 13 / express.js with node-postgres for a test project. I have a table in Postgresql that contains a column where it holds an array of questions for an evaluation form (I made it as JSON as the questions can be edited to have more or lesser questions, dynamic form stuff).

With this idea, I made two tables: `EvalForm` and `DefaultForm`

`EvalForm` has `id (PK, INT), job_id, form_type (INT), form_questions (JSONB), and form_answers (JSONB)`.

`DefaultForm` has `id (PK, INT) and form_questions(JSONB)`.

The logic is that the `form_type` value will correspond to what `form_questions` will be copied based on its `id`. (e.g. `form_type` = 1, then it will copy the form_questions with `id` = 1 from `DefaultForm` table).

I would like to be able to copy the entire JSONB array and insert it into another table. I've read about `jsonb_build_object` and `jsonb_agg()`, but I'm not sure how to use them for my use-case.

Thank you in advance for the help!

This is currently the query that I've worked on, only missing on how to get JSONB as I can't cast type record to JSONB.

```
const type = await pool.query('SELECT job_type FROM jobs WHERE id = $1', [
  req.params.id
]);

 const sqlString = 'WITH questions AS (
 SELECT form_questions
FROM DefaultForm WHERE id = $2
 INSERT INTO EvalForm (
job_id, form_type, form_questions)
  SELECT $1, $2, questions::jsonb
FROM questions';

 const sqlValues = [req.params.id, type.rows[0].job_type
 ];
```

Comment: Why do you want to copy the questions at all (instead of just referencing them)?

Comment: @Bergie as the DefaultForm can be changed / updated, and referencing them will cause inconsistencies in the future (e.g. currently there are 6 questions in the DefaultForm, which makes it neede to have 6 answers in EvalForm. In the future if user decides to change the questions, reduce or increase the number of questions, the  EvalForm row will then update itself to the new DefaultForm, which is something I want to avoid.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonb_agg` is the right choice, you're looking for

```
INSERT INTO EvalForm (job_id, form_type, form_questions)
SELECT $1, $2, jsonb_agg(form_questions)
FROM DefaultForm
WHERE id = $2;
```